# Auto Crop Picture From Scanned Document

Tags: vb.net, crop, imaging

i am working on a project where i have to scan a lot of pages (application form) where each form is attached (pasted with glue) with application picture. So, i need to get the picture (crop only the picture) from that scanned page/document.

I have attached a sample..

[image]

i can set the exact location on the document/image but few issues with that:
1. attached/pasted image is not on same size..
2. it may be not be pasted on same place on each form
3. it may be rotated slightly..

so, i am looking for some automated process that can take out the picture correctly regardless the above issues. i assume face detection may be the tool, but i am not sure about that..

so, it would be great if any one can help me with that?

thanks in advance

any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: When you say you've attached a "sample", is that truly a sample that you're working with, or is it actual personal details you've just put online?  Either way, this question is a little broad for Stack Overflow

Comment: Do you want to eliminate the picture from the scan or extract the contents of it?  Either way, I imagine that you'll have to analyze the scan image contents to detect the borders of where the picture starts.  The key would be to determine a relative range of colors for the contents of the non-picture parts of the document and then find a way to determine where, in the picture, you go "off range" and then somehow remove (or replace) those pixels. What type of image does the scan produce? JPG? PNG? BMP?

Comment: @ChicagoMike yes sir, you got it  but that's leads to lot of task and also as i told in my post image is not always the same size and also not the alignment and positioning is same. so, i think there is already some easier way exits rather the research on it for months? :( like face detection or color tone etc? thanks again for your reply sir...

Comment: I think it would be a cool experiment to check each pixel to see whether the color value falls within a given range and then take out those which fall outside of the range.  It's a little crude, maybe, but not too difficult.

Comment: @ChicagoMike, but sir, don't you think check pixel by pixel will take so long where i have thousands of thousands paper/form to process? btw thanks again for your reply...

Comment: You could also look at some open source libraries like [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/) which includes face detection.

Comment: any help please? PS: emucV is not good for this :(